# PyQt5 application freezes after 8h

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore, qml, pyqt5, qt5

I have an application in PyQt5 (python3) with two subscribers on a firestore database. After 8-10 hours the GUI freezes without any error. 34 threads of the python script are running. 28 threads have 0% CPU load, one has 100% (main QML thread) and 3 about 2%. The QML part starts already 12 threads.

The code was tested on 2 different armhf boards with the same issue. On normal run, the QML thread runs at 35% CPU load.

The problem might be the firestore reconnect, but I'm not sure:

Because the firestore server disconnects every 60min I have to check the connection and reconnect.
The issue is described on github: [Firestore listener stops receiving changes after a long time running without throwing an error #294](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-python/issues/294)

In my program I have solved this with a QTimer by checking the _closed flag:

```
class FirestoreConnector():

   def __init__(self, on_snapshot):
       self._on_snapshot = on_snapshot
       self.start_snapshot()

   def start_snapshot(self):
       self._watcher = db.document(u'dataset').on_snapshot(self._on_snapshot)

   def check_if_online(self):
       if self._watcher._closed:
           print('connection closed:', time.ctime())
           self.start_snapshot()
```

The snapshot function receives changes and updates the global object:

```
def on_snapshot_device(docs, changes, read_time):
   try:
       datasetStorage.update(changes) # object with synced data
       for change in changes:
            print("Change: {}".format(change))
            if change.type.name == 'ADDED':
               print(u'added: {}'.format(change.document.id))

   except Exception as err:
       print(err)
       print("Error occurred at " + str(time.ctime()))
       traceback.print_exc()
```

The QTimer is running at 1Hz:

```
firestore_connection = FirestoreConnector(on_snapshot_device)
timer = QtCore.QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(firestore_connection.check_if_online)
timer.start(1000)
```

**UPDATE:**

---

I have deactivated all threads which could lead to a raise condition. But even without the firebase reconnect thread and without the serial read thread the system freezes.

On a x64 system I have seen, that the Qt5 thread stopped after activating the display from sleep mode. Another armhf system is just running since a few days, there I was able to deactivate the display sleep mode.

Comment: Are you sure you have not created some sort of Thread Blocker situation either Deadlock or Livelock?  Also you stated you are using multiple threads and that one particular Thread is taking up all the CPU -- so have you set up an endless loop within that thread perhaps some how that for some reason does not get triggered right away? If you can figure out what the 100% Thread is doing that might help you get to the root of your issue.

Comment: @DennisJensen I have deactivated all threads for testing and it freezes also. So I came to the camera which is handled by a QtObject. On a Jetson Nano the syslog filled my disk space with errors from the nv-argus daemon. Deactivating syslog solved this issue on the Jetson. I have also removed a code in QML which took care of starting and stopping the camera when the camera view is closed. Starting and stopping was maybe triggered twice. It runs now for more than 10h. The weird thing is, that it freezes even if the camera stream wasn't started.

Comment: Okay so it sounds like it was "freezing" because of a continuous error taking up all the CPU so it was basically the endless loop that was firing so fast that nothing else could process. So whatever is causing the error may not be directly connected to starting the camera stream but with something else that the program fires up.  Hope you can determine and let us all know what that is/was.

Comment: @DennisJensen it makes no sense to me, today the system was running for about 13h. There is a USB device connected with a virtual serial port. I read it every 500ms with a readline(), but before I check the in_waiting flag in an if-statement to exit or read out the data. My thought was, that the connection gets broken when it comes into the readline() function. Because when I restart the application without disconnecting the USB devices, I cannot read or write anything, but I also receive no serial error. This would explain why it stops the main thread and the other threads are working.

Comment: I realize this adds another layer and thus a potential issue to the situation but I would try logging the events around where you suspect the issue to be. For instance append to a simple text file a text line like "Starting Read of Serial Port" then when you have completed it "Concluded Read of Serial Port" this way you will know if it hangs there. You might add a time to Start and Conclude perhaps its something that for some reason slowly degrades -- aka takes longer and longer until it hangs kind of thing. Basically any additional information is going to help shed more light on the situation

Comment: I'm working in pycharm with the build-in debugger. I print out messages in each thread which are transmitted to my PC over ssh. Because it takes more than 10h to receive the error it takes me very long to find the problem. I have commented out already a few functions that could lead to the problem. Last time it stopped at the serial read thread. But I have already deactivated the read function and it happened also. Tomorrow I will set up a few systems with the same hardware and different code. Maybe I can isolate the problem and share more important parts from the code.